# Sufficient conditions for foldl and foldr equivalence

Tags: haskell, fold

Consider the expressions `E1 = foldl op acc l` and `E2 = foldr op acc l`.

What are some natural sufficient conditions for `op`, `acc` and/or `l` that guarantee the equivalence of `E1`and `E2`?

A naive example would be that if `op`is constant then both are equivalent.

I'm pretty sure there must be precise conditions involving commutativity and/or associativity of `op`, and/or finitude of `l`, and/or neutrality of `acc`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `op` is an associative operation, `acc` is a neutral element of `op`, and `l` is finite, then they are equivalent.

Indeed, the result of `foldr` is

```
(l1 `op` (l2 `op` ... (ln `op` acc)))
```

while that of `foldl` is

```
(((acc `op` l1) `op` l2) `op` ... ln)
```

To prove that they are equal, it suffices to simplify `acc` away, and reassociate.

---

Even if `acc` is not a neutral element, but `acc` still satisfies the weaker condition

```
forall x,  acc `op` x = x `op` acc
```

then, if `op` is associative and `l` is finite, we again get the desired equivalence.

To prove this, we can exploit the fact that `acc` commutes with everything, and "move" it from the tail position to the head one, exploiting associativity. E.g.

```
(l1 `op` (l2 `op` acc))
=
(l1 `op` (acc `op` l2))
=
((l1 `op` acc) `op` l2)
=
((acc `op` l1) `op` l2)
```

In the question it is mentioned the sufficient condition `op = const k` which is associative but has no neutral element. Still, any `acc` commutes with everything, so the "constant `op`" case is a subcase of the above sufficient condition.

---

Assuming `op` has a neutral element `acc`, if we assume

```
foldr op acc [a,b,c] = foldl op acc [a,b,c]      -- (*)
```

we derive

```
a `op` (b `op` c) = (a `op` b) `op` c
```

Hence, If `(*)` holds for all `a,b,c`, then `op` has to be associative. Associativity is then necessary and sufficient (when a neutral element exists).

---

If `l` is infinite, `foldl` always diverges no matter what `op,acc` are. If `op` is strict on its second argument, `foldr` also diverges (i.e., it returns bottom).

Comment: According to [the diagrams in this link](https://gist.github.com/CMCDragonkai/9f5f75118dda10131764) the most inner operation always involves `acc` as a left/right operator respectively, so I think this might be mistaken.

Comment: @Jsevillamol Thanks. I was too fast to remove the neutral element requirement. Restored.

Comment: Regarding the case where `l` is infinitve: if we take` op` which is strict on its second argument to be for example the list constructor `:` then the result is an infinite list that you can still use lazily. So I think that this argument is not sensitive to different kinds of $\bottom$ values, if that makes sense.

Comment: @Jsevillamol Note that the list constructor `:` is _not_ strict in Haskell, in both arguments. E.g. `seq (undefined : undefined) ()` will happily terminate. Infinite lists are also not considered bottom values.

Comment: Can you specify exactly what do you mean by 'diverges'? Is it possible to use `foldl` to create an infinite value different from bottom?

Comment: @Jsevillamol For instance, `foldr (+) 0 [1..]` is bottom. Instead, `foldr (:) [] [1..]` is `[1..]` which is not bottom. (Above, with "diverges" I mean the result is bottom). With `foldl ` you always get a bottom value with an infinite list. You can only get an infinite value in trivial cases e.g. `foldr op [1..] []`, or when `op` itself produces (after finitely many applications) an infinite value.

Comment: @chi note: I think you mean `foldl op [1..] []` above (took me a second).

Comment: @luqui Indeed, in my comment I meant `foldl` as you point out.